# concurrent modification exception for set iterator

Tags: java, exception, collections, concurrentmodification

Hi I have the following code structure

```
    Private Set<String> someset = null; //a class variable

    someclassfunction() {
       Set<String> st = mapA.keyset();
       someset = mapA.keyset();

       for (String s: st) { //this is where now the exception occurs
            someotherclassfunction();
       }
    }

    someotherclassfunction() {
       Iterator<String> it = someset.iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           String key = it.next();
           if (somecondition) {
               it.remove();
           //Earlier I did, someset.remove(key), this threw concurrent
           //modification exception at this point. So I found on stack 
           //overflow that we need to use iterator to remove
           }
       }
    }
```

But now the same exception occurs on the calling function for each loop. Why is that? I am not modifying the st set, I am modifying the someset (class variable). Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code:

```
Set<String> st = mapA.keyset();
someset = mapA.keyset();
```

Both `someset` and `st` point to the same set. So you're actually removing from the set you're iterating upon in the `for-each` loop in your first method.

Comment: So how do I fix it? I need a referring copy (someset) which will be modified, but not the original copy (st)

Comment: @ArnavSengupta You need to create copy of the `mapA.keySet()`.

Comment: So will Set<String> anotherSet = mapA.keyset(), and then someset = anotherSet fix it?

Comment: You do `Set<String> anotherSet = new HashSet<>(mapA.keySet());` Same for the other set.

Comment: @RohitJain that is not thread save, as the copy constructor action is not atomic it sadly iterates over the keySet, and when that is changed while copying you still get the concurrent modification.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outer for loop unless you need to pass something to the someotherclassfunction() from s.
So changing the below;

```
for (String s: st) { //this is where now the exception occurs
      someotherclassfunction();
}
```

to

```
someotherclassfunction();
```

should get rid of the ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: I need it to be called for each s in st. What Rohit answered above is indeed right. Thanks anyway!